# namespace handler for for neo4j spring data error

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Hello this error i've been getting when i try to run a main test on my neo4j spring data project

Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [neo4j.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension

thank you for your help i really appreaciate it

Comment: You are probably mixing some incompatible framework versions. What is your Neo4j and Spring Data Neo4j version? Do you use maven? If not, make sure Spring Data Commons is available on the classpath.

Comment: i use neo4j server 2.0.0 community with its libs , and spring framework 2.5.4 libs , and i don't use maven , spring data commons is available on the class path

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j 2.0 is not yet supported in Spring Data Neo4j. I'd suggest you use 1.9 or abandon SDN for now. You're also better of using Spring 3. This is the combination I'm currently working with:

- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:1.9  (use this version for neo4j-server as well)
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: if i can ask you use only those jars ?

Comment: No, there will be other dependencies but I don't know them by hart. You're better of using a build tool like e.g. Maven. It will pull all necessary dependencies. Adding the spring-data-neo4j module to your project dependencies list is all you have to do.

Comment: the thing is that i haven't worked with maven yet ... i'm gonna give it a try , thank you once again

Comment: it haven't worked , with those jars , everything is fine , except those warning about the namespace handlers as it seems there is an error in the neo4-2.2.xsd and the previous versions issue those warnings ...

Comment: Which xsd are you talking about? Make sure you use the correct xsd versions (= matching the release versions).